# YouTube-iFrame-API doesn't work on Chrome v.72

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

"player.play()" doesn't work on Chrome(v.72). This bug happens on windows7 and Android phone.(I don't know about iOS.)
It works well on other versions.
Is there anyone who knows about this bug?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.

Adding allow="autoplay" to my parent iframe fixed it as well

Answer (score 2):

Is your youtube iframe wrapped in another iframe (crossdomain)?

If so then it could be caused by the new user activation api v2 (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/user-activation)?

And you can solve the issue by adding the allow="autoplay" attribute to your parent iframe.

It didn't make 100% sense to me at first but it fixed the issue we had.