# Why my YouTube Iframe API video turns off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a problem with **YouTube Iframe API**. I have a **Slick slider** with pictures and videos from YouTube. One slide - one video or one picture. Slick has dots and is draggable. I'm trying to write a **functionallity: video starts to play when its slide is active**. Without clicking on 'play' button - it starts when I open its slide automatically. **My problem is that my video starts, yup. But it also turns off in one second.** And it's not automatically play anymore on slide change. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="video-banner" id="{{ yt }}" data-ytid="{{ yt }}"></div>
```

```js
(function($){
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        $('.video-banner').each(function() {
          yt_id = $(this).data("ytid");
          playerInfo.push({ "id": yt_id, 'videoId': yt_id, 'slick_id': $(this).closest('.slick-slide').data('slick-index') });
        });
  
        for (var i = 0; i < playerInfo.length; i++) {
          var curplayer = createPlayer(playerInfo[i]);
          players[i] = curplayer;
        }
      }

      function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
      }
  
      function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
        return new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
          videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
          host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
          width: '100%',
          height: 500,
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 0,
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          },
        });
      }
      
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("?yt=") > -1) {
          if (getParameterByName('yt') == event.target.getVideoData().video_id) {
            event.target.playVideo();
          }
        }
      }
  
      $(slider).on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        for (var i = 0; i < playerInfo.length; i++) {
          if (playerInfo[i].slick_id == currentSlide) {
            if (typeof players[i].playVideo === "function")
              players[i].playVideo();
          }
        }
      });
    
    });
}(jQuery))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the video wasn't muted. Browsers sometimes block iframes without muted sounds.
On the other hand: I work on Chrome, see: [YouTube-iFrame-API doesn't work on Chrome v.72](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54457759/youtube-iframe-api-doesnt-work-on-chrome-v-72).